# Grails 3.0.1 add in Eclipse show error Specified directory does not appear to be a Grails installation

Tags: eclipse, grails, ggts

When I try to install/import Grails 3.0.1 in Eclipse I get error message 
"Specified directory does not appear to be a Grails installation".

I already have installed Groovy Compiler 2.4.3. but still get same error message.

How I can install Grails 3.0.1 in Eclipse 4.4?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

At grails folder you can put a file "build.properties",

```
/grails-3.0.1/build.properties
             /install
             /license
             /.......
```

the content of this file is a single line "grails.version=3.0.1", without quotes. :-)

Now eclipse will recognize it as Grails installation.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Andgau! This was exactly what I needed. After creating the file, I was able to add grails-3.0.1 as the preferred grails version. It remains to be seen if the rest of the IDE features work :-)

Comment: Same here, this post should be the answer! Thank you very much Andgau!

Comment: This worked perfectly on grails-3.1.1 also!  Thanks Andgau!

Comment: Worked. Sometimes I read SO answers and wonder how people figure these things out!

Answer (score 11):

Grails 3 is very different from earlier versions of Grails, in particular being based on Spring Boot. It will be a while before the IDEs have support for Grails 3. Eclipse will probably not have support for Grails 3 as 3.6.4 has been announced as the last release of GGTS and the Grails and Groovy tooling now that Pivotal has abandoned Grails and Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

I use the lattest ggts from sping (3.6.4) the gradle plugin (installed over the spring dashboard) and the latest snapshot release of the groovy plugin for eclipse to get a groovy 2.4 compiler.

With this setup import your grails3 application as gradle application works for me.

Comment: I was able to import as a Gradle application, but then I can't run / debug the project as a Grails app, because Eclipse just sees it as a Gradle project.  I am wondering if the other Grails features (like autocomplete) will work as well.  Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps for working with Grails 3 in Eclipse.
1) Get latest grails 3.X version and setup in the system.
2) Now create grails app using command line.
3) Install Gradle plugin in eclipse if not already there.
4) Import project as Gradle in eclipse, Gradle will download all required dependencies.

Comment: Following this path does not seem to give you a "Grails" project - in that you can't do all of the Grails things with it.  See my comment on Mirko's answer.